# Ballerina is not upgrading to 1.1.0. After upgrading to Ballerina to version 1.1.0, it still shows that I have version 1.0.x?

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I'm on Mac OS High Sierra and when I click on the installer to upgrade to Ballerina 1.1.0, it installs with no error messages but when I type in `ballerina version` , it still shows that I have the older 1.0.5.

```
ballerina version
```

Output:

```
Ballerina 1.0.5
Language specification 2019R3
```

When I type in `which ballerina`, I still get the following despite upgrading with the installer:

```
/Library/Ballerina/ballerina-1.0.5/bin/ballerina
```

How do I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

When the installer is run, it should ideally set up the path to the new executable for you. Conflicts may arise because in the previous versions of Ballerina (1.0.0, 1.0.5 etc.) it was installed (defaults in Mac) under:

```
/Library/Ballerina/ballerina-1.0.x
```

**Old (1.0.x) Bin Folder**

```
/Library/Ballerina/ballerina-1.0.x/bin
```

So if you have manually configured the BALLERINA_HOME environment variable and added the bin directory to your path (when you had the old versions), it will still show that you have the old version of ballerina when you look for `ballerina version`

There seems to have been a small change in Ballerina 1.1.0 where it installs directly into `/Library/Ballerina/` so the new bin folder location to find the ballerina executable is:

**1.1.0 Bin Folder**

```
/Library/Ballerina/bin
```

So once again, if you have made modifications in your bash script to manually configure the path in the previous versions it might break with the 1.1.0 version. Edit your startup script (I use `~/.bashrc`) to add/edit the new BALLERINA_HOME variable to your path by doing the following:

```
BALLERINA_HOME=/Library/Ballerina
export PATH=$PATH:$BALLERINA_HOME/bin
```

Then source/execute your script (I use `. ~/.bashrc`) and it should now work.

```
ballerina version
```

Output:

```
jBallerina 1.1.0
Language specification 2019R3
Ballerina tool 0.8.0
```

Comment: If you have manually set Ballerina home location it will always pick that location. From 1.1.0 release, it will install to /Library/Ballerina/ instead of creating another directory. Reason behind that is we have introduced ballerina tool to manage versions. There from the tool itself we let users to fetch new releases instead of reinstalling. You can find new more information on that from following blog post.
https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/ballerina-tool-for-distribution-management-4dbd638d003a